# "Your Phone Companion" only works on unlocked phone

Tags: applications, samsung, security, lock-screens

I do not know if this is a bug or a feature, but it does not make much sense.

I have a Samsung S9, and I managed to connect it to my Windows 10 laptop. I can only start apps when my phone is unlocked, and this is annoying:

- If I need to pick up my phone anyway to unlock it, I might as well just use that, instead of my laptop
- Why should I waste electricity on two screens?

Is there any solution?

Comment: the tag is likely wrong, but I have no better idea.

Comment: It's a security, issue and likely a feature and not a bug. You can try automation with [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) and create a simple macro to reduce screen brightness and save current, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkKJ7.jpg) //You can use any other [tag:automation] apps

Comment: Most devices have an option in the "Developer options" menu to keep screen on when connected to a PC. I assume this should also prevent auto-locking of the device.

Comment: @Robert yes, good one, forgot about that - OP can combine both our suggestions //Feel free to make an answer using my or any other suggestions to reduce screen brightness and save electricity

Answer (score 0):

when laptop accessing some data from your Samsung galaxy mobile. Your mobile should be unlocked. Security features hinder access of phone. You can temporary disable screen lock.
And reduce brightness of the mobile so less battery will be used.

Comment: The brightness is important but not because of the power saving but to prevent/slow-down the OLED display from burn-in long shown images. In any way a typical smartphone display consumes less that 2 Watt, hence the amount of power that can be saved is very very low.

Comment: Read his question He do not want to waste electricity. Less brightness less power used. Any way thanks for reply.